# Facebook API and iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, api, server-side

I have a question as I have been looking for the answer on google, but I don't know how to phrase it correctly :P.

I am writing a little app for iOS using Facebook API. I would like apps to communicate between each other, not  a lot, just a little bit of data, between users who use that app. Does Facebook support something like that or do I have to implement my own server side in order to have such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook doesn't support anything like that. You will have to develop your own backend for something such as that. Each of the App's Users who log into Facebook, create a corresponding User in your backend database, storing the Facebook ID of that person. Now you're building your own database where you can handle relationships, and communicate with each other.

Comment: Thanks! I know that was a stupid question but at least I know the answer. Can I freely store users ID's in my own database, or would that be consider sharing personal data with 3rd parties?

Comment: You can use whatever you ask permissions for, in your own database.